# Dynamic SQL to generate column names?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have a query where I'm trying pivot row values into column names and currently I'm using `SUM(Case...) As 'ColumnName'` statements, like so:

```
SELECT
SKU1,
SUM(Case When Sku2=157 Then Quantity Else 0 End) As '157',
SUM(Case When Sku2=158 Then Quantity Else 0 End) As '158',
SUM(Case When Sku2=167 Then Quantity Else 0 End) As '167'
FROM
OrderDetailDeliveryReview
Group By
OrderShipToID,
DeliveryDate,
SKU1
```

The above query works great and gives me exactly what I need.  However, I'm writing out the `SUM(Case...` statements by hand based on the results of the following query:

```
Select Distinct Sku2 From OrderDetailDeliveryReview
```

Is there a way, using T-SQL inside a stored procedure, that I can dynamically generate the `SUM(Case...` statements from the `Select Distinct Sku2 From OrderDetailDeliveryReview` query and then execute the resulting SQL code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Having answered a lot of these over the years by generating dynamic pivot SQL from the metadata, have a look at these examples:

[SQL Dynamic Pivot - how to order columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122117/sql-dynamic-pivot-how-to-order-columns)

[SQL Server 2005 Pivot on Unknown Number of Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213702/sql-server-2005-pivot-on-unknown-number-of-columns)

[What SQL query or view will show "dynamic columns"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219559/what-sql-query-or-view-will-show-dynamic-columns)

[How do I Pivot on an XML column's attributes in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580077/how-do-i-pivot-on-an-xml-columns-attributes-in-t-sql)

[How to apply the DRY principle to SQL Statements that Pivot Months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463377/how-to-apply-the-dry-principle-to-sql-statements-that-pivot-months)

In your particular case (using the ANSI pivot instead of SQL Server 2005's PIVOT feature):

```
DECLARE @template AS varchar(max)
SET @template = 'SELECT 
SKU1
{COLUMN_LIST}
FROM
OrderDetailDeliveryReview
Group By
OrderShipToID,
DeliveryDate,
SKU1
'

DECLARE @column_list AS varchar(max)
SELECT @column_list = COALESCE(@column_list, ',') + 'SUM(Case When Sku2=' + CONVERT(varchar, Sku2) + ' Then Quantity Else 0 End) As [' + CONVERT(varchar, Sku2) + '],' 
FROM OrderDetailDeliveryReview
GROUP BY Sku2
ORDER BY Sku2

Set @column_list = Left(@column_list,Len(@column_list)-1)

SET @template = REPLACE(@template, '{COLUMN_LIST}', @column_list)

EXEC (@template)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I've seen a lot of answers that use `COALESCE`, but what exactly is that function doing?

Comment: Also, If I try to run your query as-is, I get an error on Line 15: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'."  If I remove the comma at the end of line 14, I then get an error message on *line 3* that says "Incorrect syntax near 'SUM'" Any ideas on what's going on here or how to debug this?

Comment: @Cade Roux Ok, I tweaked the code (put the comma within the quotes at the end of line 14; added a line to trim the comma off of @column_list). Now it works, which is great, but I can't figure out what's going on between lines 14 and 17.

Comment: @Ben McCormack Sorry for the typos.  COALESCE(x, y, z) returns the first non-NULL argument.  For two parameters, it's basically performing the same function as ISNULL(x, y) (but is more ANSI).  The SELECT @var = @var + something from TABLE is a SQL Server quirky thing you can do which just keep appending to one variable to make the column list, which is then simply inserted in the template.

Comment: thanks again for your response. While I was trying to figure this out, I posted a new question to try to figure out what's going on with the variable assignment, but you may have answered it already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555568/what-is-happening-in-this-t-sql-code

Answer (score 2):

I know that SO search engine is not perfect, but your question has been answered in [SQL Server PIVOT Column Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984306/sql-server-pivot-column-data).
Also see [Creating cross tab queries and pivot tables in SQL](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/creating-cross-tab-queries-and-pivot-tables-in-sql/).

Comment: @van i found out that by prefixing my programming queries like this, `StackOverflow SQL Server Pivot`, I get to Bing the site well (although the "other" legacy engine is good :D too)

Comment: FYI for anyone who doesn't know: I typically use Google: "site:stackoverflow.com sql server dynamic pivot cade roux" to find all my previous answers on this (or any) topic.

Answer (score 1):

Why do this using hard coded column names when you can pull all this dynamically from any table?

Using UNPIVOT and COALESCE, I can dynamically pull a list of columns from any table and associated column values for any record in a record listing and combine them in a list of column names with values by row. Here is the code. Just drop in your database and table name. The column/value table will be generated for you in SQL Server. Keep in mind, to get a shared column of values for the columns you want to convert to sql variant or text strings. But a great way to get a sample column list of values with matching column names and types with our while loops or cursors. Its pretty fast:

```
-- First get a list of all known columns in your database, dynamically...
DECLARE @COLUMNS nvarchar(max)
SELECT @COLUMNS = 

CASE
 WHEN A.DATA_TYPE = 'nvarchar' OR A.DATA_TYPE = 'ntext' THEN 
COALESCE(@COLUMNS + ',','') + 'CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar(4000),['+A.[name]+']) AS sql_variant) AS ['+A.[name]+']'
 WHEN A.DATA_TYPE = 'datetime' OR A.DATA_TYPE = 'smalldatetime' THEN 
COALESCE(@COLUMNS + ',','') + 'CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar,['+A.[name]+'],101) AS sql_variant) AS ['+A.[name]+']'
 ELSE
 COALESCE(@COLUMNS + ',','') + 'CAST(['+A.[name]+'] AS sql_variant) AS ['+A.[name]+']'
 END

FROM
(
 SELECT
 A.name,
 C.DATA_TYPE
 FROM YOURDATABASENAME.dbo.syscolumns A
 INNER JOIN YOURDATABASENAME.dbo.sysobjects B ON B.id = A.id
 LEFT JOIN
 (
 SELECT 
COLUMN_NAME,
 DATA_TYPE
 FROM YOURDATABASENAME.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YOURTABLENAME' 
) C ON C.COLUMN_NAME = A.name
 WHERE B.name = 'YOURTABLENAME'
 AND C.DATA_TYPE <> 'timestamp' 
) A
-- Test that the formatted columns list is returned...
--SELECT @COLUMNS

-- This gets a second string list of all known columns in your database, dynamically...
DECLARE @COLUMNS2 nvarchar(max)
SELECT @COLUMNS2 = COALESCE(@COLUMNS2 + ',','') + '['+A.[name]+']'
FROM
(
 SELECT
 A.name,
 C.DATA_TYPE
 FROM YOURDATABASENAME.dbo.syscolumns A
 INNER JOIN YOURDATABASENAME.dbo.sysobjects B ON B.id = A.id
 LEFT JOIN
 (
 SELECT 
COLUMN_NAME,
 DATA_TYPE
 FROM YOURDATABASENAME.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YOURTABLENAME' 
) C ON C.COLUMN_NAME = A.name
 WHERE B.name = 'YOURTABLENAME'
 AND C.DATA_TYPE <> 'timestamp' 
) A
-- Test that the formatted columns list is returned...
--SELECT @COLUMNS2


-- Now plug in the list of the dynamic columns list into an UNPIVOT to get a Column Name / Column Value list table...
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @sql = 
'
SELECT
ColumnName,ColumnValue
FROM
(
SELECT
'+@COLUMNS+'
FROM YOURDATABASENAME.dbo.YOURTABLENAME  
WHERE CHANGE_ID IN (SELECT ChangeId FROM YOURDATABASENAME.dbo.OperatorProcess WHERE OperatorProcessID = 3)
) AS SourceTable
UNPIVOT
(
ColumnValue FOR ColumnName IN ('+@COLUMNS2+')
) AS PivotTable
'

EXEC (@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Darshankar Madhusudan i can do dynamic columnheading table easly...
--thanks  
declare @incr int = 1,
        @col  int,
        @str varchar(max),
        @tblcrt varchar(max),
        @insrt varchar(max),
        set @tblcrt = 'DECLARE @Results table ('        
        set @str = ''      
        set @insrt = ''  
    select @col = max(column_id) From tempdb.sys.all_columns    where object_id = object_id('tempdb.dbo.#aaa')
    while @incr <= @col
        BEGIN
             SELECT @STR = @STR    +case when @incr = 1 then '''' else ',''' end +rtrim(ltrim(NAME))+'''' FROM TEMPDB.SYS.ALL_COLUMNS    WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB.DBO.#AAA') and column_id = @incr 
             set @tblcrt = @tblcrt + case when @incr = 1 then '' else ',' end + 'Fld'+CAST(@incr as varchar(3)) +' varchar(50)'
             set @insrt = @insrt   + case when @incr = 1 then '' else ',' end + 'Fld'+CAST(@incr as varchar(3))
             SET @INCR = @INCR + 1 
        END 
        set @tblcrt = @tblcrt + ')'
        set @insrt = 'insert into @Results('+@insrt+') values (' + @STR +')'
        set @tblcrt = @tblcrt+ ';' + @insrt + 'select * from @Results '
exec(@tblcrt)
```