# What is happening in this T-SQL code? (Concatenting the results of a SELECT statement)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I'm just starting to learn T-SQL and could use some help in understanding what's going on in a particular block of code.  I modified some code in [an answer I received in a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554826/dynamic-sql-to-generate-column-names/2555102#2555102), and here is the code in question:

```
DECLARE @column_list AS varchar(max) 
SELECT @column_list = COALESCE(@column_list, ',') + 
    'SUM(Case When Sku2=' + CONVERT(varchar, Sku2) + 
    ' Then Quantity Else 0 End) As [' + 
    CONVERT(varchar, Sku2) + ' - ' + 
    Convert(varchar,Description) +'],'
FROM OrderDetailDeliveryReview 
Inner Join InvMast on SKU2 = SKU and LocationTypeID=4
GROUP BY Sku2 , Description
ORDER BY Sku2 

Set @column_list = Left(@column_list,Len(@column_list)-1)

Select @column_list

----------------------------------------

1 row is returned:
,SUM(Case When Sku2=157 Then Quantity Else 0 End) As [157 -..., SUM(Case ...
```

The T-SQL code does exactly what I want, which is to make a single result based on the results of a query, which will then be used in another query.

However, I can't figure out how the `SELECT @column_list =...` statement is putting multiple values into a single string of characters by being inside a `SELECT` statement.  Without the assignment to `@column_list`, the `SELECT` statement would simply return multiple rows.  How is it that by having the variable within the `SELECT` statement that the results get "flattened" down into one value? How should I read this T-SQL to properly understand what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server:

```
SELECT @var = @var + col
FROM TABLE
```

actually concatenates the values. It's a quirks mode (and I am unable at this time to find a reference to the documentation of feature - which has been used for years in the SQL Server community).  If @var is NULL at the start (i.e. an uninitialized value), then you need a COALESCE or ISNULL (and you'll often use a separator):

```
SELECT @var = ISNULL(@var, '') + col + '|'
FROM TABLE
```

or this to make a comma-separated list, and then remove only the leading comma:

```
SELECT @var = ISNULL(@var, '') + ',' + col
FROM TABLE

SET @var = STUFF(@var, 1, 1, '')
```

or (courtesy of [KM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65223/km), relying on NULL + ',' yielding NULL to eliminate the need for STUFF for the first item in the list):

```
SELECT @var = ISNULL(@var + ',', '') + col
FROM TABLE
```

or this to make a list with a leading, separated and trailing comma:

```
SELECT @var = ISNULL(@var, ',') + col + ','
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: don't need `STUFF()` when you do it this way: `SELECT @var=ISNULL(@var+',','')+col FROM TABLE`

Comment: @KM, yeah, let me add that technique.

Comment: it is probably more efficient to default @var to empty string: '' and eliminate the ISNULL() done for each row and just do the STUFF one time at the very end, though...

Comment: Excellect answer. Thanks for your explanation.  This is going to help a ton!

Answer (score 1):

You will want to look into the COALESCE function.  A good article describing what is happening can be seen [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1521).

Comment: @Jon - Looking into the `COALESCE` function certainly helped.  What's is that without the `COALESCE` function, `NULL` is returned.  Is this because character strings cannot be added to `NULL` values?

Comment: Hi Ben, anything added to a null will always result in a null

Comment: @Ben McCormack ANSI NULL behavior will give NULL + str -> NULL.  Non-ANSI behavior will give NULL + str -> str - you can get this non-standard behavior with SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF.

Comment: @Cade Roux Thanks for adding another comment after mine, I never knew about that!